# Josephus for-loop in Python

Tags: python-3.6, josephus

So, I tried to see if I could write code that would solve the Josephus Problem in Python for n amount of people (in the circle).

I'm an amateur, so please bear with me.

Here's the code I came up with it, but it has some problems.

```
n = input(int)

for i in range(0,10):
  if 2**i < n:
    print (2(n-(2**i))+1)
```

Firstly, it gives a TypeError and says that '<' is not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'.

Secondly, if I replace

```
n = input(int)
```

with

```
n = 100
```

then it gives the TypeError: 'int' object is not callable.

Moreover, I can't seem to understand how I'd get the program to return the true solution for n = 100 (which is 73), considering that I used a weird for-loop and it'd return solutions for every value of 2^i that's less than n all the way up till 2^10

Answer (score 0):

You are missing * in print line.
it should be

```py
print(2*(n-(2**i))+1)
```

According to your code you are calling some 2(something) where as int is not callable. your solution also isn't totally correct. It doesn't work for perfect 2 powers.

look at [this link](https://medium.com/@sudheernaidu53/the-josephus-problem-36cbf94f3a64) for different methods and proofs